# Where is this trig equation derived from?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

In the first, top rated, comment on the original post linked below, the author wrote the function $r = \dfrac {\cos(x)} {1−\cos(x)}$. I do not understand how they got to this equation. I get how they solved for $x$ in their first step. Can you please explain how they solved for $r$.

This is the picture of the problem, where we are solving for $r$, given $x = \dfrac {n-2}{2n}$

[image]

Original Post
[Numbers of circles around a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/numbers-of-circles-around-a-circle)

Comment: You have linked to a user profile, not a comment or answer.  Hence I honestly have no idea what this question is about...

Comment: I apologize, I am updating the link right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the right Triangle, we can write $\cos x $ as 
 Base divided by the hypotenuse

$$\cos x=\frac{r}{r+1}$$

$$\frac{1}{\cos x}=1+\frac{1}{r}$$

$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{\cos x}-1$$
$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x}$$
$$r=\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos x }$$

Comment: Where is the 1 from in the denominator at the beginning? Shouldn't it be r/r+L

Comment: it is the length of the hypotenuse   in the right triangle  which is $r+1$

Comment: it is 1 it is not L

Comment: you misreading 1 as L here it is 1

Comment: If my center circle radius is 100, then is it r/r+100?

Comment: yes you are correct if the raduis of the center circle is 100

Comment: I figured out that with a radius of 100, I had to make the equation r=100(cosx/1-cosx)

Comment: can I ask you how you went from your third line of math to your fourth (second to last)? How did you transfer that -1 the way you did?

Comment: @LeviKline $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{\cos x} - 1 = \frac{1}{\cos x} - \frac{\cos x}{\cos x} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{\cos x}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see, thank you. I should have thought about multiplying for a common denominator. Silly me! Thank you for the clarification.