# Why does nature prefer hexagons?

Tags: geometry, polygons

The best ratio of surface to volume in three dimensional space is the ball.

This can be easily observed with soap-bubbles, rain-drops and so on.
They "choose" this shape naturally.

Given restricted space, soap-bubbles "choose" the hexagon shape.
The hexagon can be observed on other examples, too, like honeycombs.

Is there a mathematical reason for that? 
Why are there not seven, eight, nine edges?
(anything that comes closer to a circle)

Comment: This would be an engineering question, to do with the structure and stability of the system, and how weight / load distribution occurs.

Comment: Maybe related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/why-is-a-circle-in-a-plane-surrounded-by-6-other-circles

Comment: This might be true for honeycombs, but not for soap-bubbles. There seems to be an intrinsic reason for the hexagon shape.

Comment: Can't comment on the "intelligence" of things that choose hexagon but Hexagonal Close Packing has the maximum Packing fraction in a lattice packing scenario.

Comment: read this [article](http://www.livescience.com/38242-why-honeybee-honeycombs-are-perfect.html) about how the cells start of as circles, and then are shaped by heat + wax into hexagons.

Comment: I never wanted to ascribe intelligence to things. It is just because I have no better description on how those things come to the shape.

Comment: The basalt columns at [the Giants' Causeway](http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/009/cache/giants-causeway_974_990x742.jpg) are mostly hexagonal also, probably for the same reason: the columns start out circular, and as they grow they tend to pack into a hexagonal lattice because that's the lowest-energy packing.  Then they continue to grow into the spaces left over between the circles, thus becoming hexagons.

Comment: My guess is that it's the closest regular shape to a circle that can completely tile a surface with no gaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hexagonal patterns occur in two dimensions essentially.
Consider an infinte set of points (vertices) in the plane joined by edges, forming an infinite graph.
[image: Photo taken by Stefan Kühn. Released under the GNU Free Documentation License.]

We can ignore vertices of degree 1 (dead ends) and of degree 2 (not distinguished from a point of an edge).
We can also ignore the case of degree $\ge 4$ as so many edges incident with one vertex would be highly coincidental.
Thus all vertices have degree $3$.
Now if we cut out some large but finite portion of this infinite graoh with $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces, then Euler says that $v+f=e+2$. 
The cutting will turn about $\sqrt v$ vertices (say $c\sqrt v$ for some small $c$) into degree $2$ vertices.
By counting edge-vertex incidences, we find $3v-c\sqrt v=2e$.
The cutting produced one outer face that is a $c'\sqrt v$-gon for some small $c'\ge c$.
For $\nu=3,4,\ldots$, let $f_\nu$ be the number of $\nu$-gonal faces apart from that outer face. Then $1+\sum f_\nu=f$ and $c'\sqrt v+\sum\nu f_\nu=2e$.
Plug this into Euler to obtain
$$ 12 = 6f+6v-6e=\sum(6-\nu)f_\nu+6+(2c-c')\sqrt v.$$
Especially, $f\approx \frac12v$ as $v$ gets large and each $\nu$-gon with $\nu>6$ must be "cancelled" by a $5$-gon or lower. In fact, any $\nu>10$ requires *at least* two small-gons and thus *should* be somewhat unusual.

So even in irregular patterns (as oppoesed to honeycombs), the (irregular) hexagon is the *average* and (though that does not follow immediately from the above) the dominant/typical shape.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being thick and missing the point here...when I look at the image of the cracked dirt, I see lots of 3, 4, and 5-gons, but I can't find a single shape that is unambiguously an irregular hexagon. Is this a counterexample, or is it a subtle illustration of your argument that's going over my head?